# Open source library to remove motion blur from video frames?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have a set of frames extracted from a video and want to remove motion blur effects (that are primarily in one dimension only). Are there any open source libraries that do this? I couldn't find anything in OpenCV. I've found a lot of academic papers on the subject, but was hoping there might be a library.

Answer (score 0):

avisynth, I think, can do this.
Sorry, spoke too soon. avisynth can do frame interpolation, good for changing sampling rate. And it can do frame repair, to interpolate what a frame should be based on its neighbors. I do not recall an exact de-blur option.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Matlab/C codes for a motion deblurring algorithm here: http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~aagrawal/MotionBlur/index.html

You will need to port Matlab/C codes to OpenCV.

Comment: the link says www.umiacs.umd.edu page is not found!

Answer (score 0):

Blind deconvolution using alternating maximum a posteriori estimation with heavy-tailed priors is one of possible method, but it is very slow. See http://zoi.utia.cas.cz/deconv_sparsegrad